# Conflict between copy constructor and a template constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I need to create a class which should roughly look like this:

```
class C {
public:
    C() = delete;
    C(const C&) = default;
    C(C&&) = default;

    template <typename ...T>
    explicit C(const T&...) { /* implementation */ };
};
```

Here is a problem with this class: case when I want copy construction is indistinguishable from the case when I want to call template constructor with a single argument of type `C`.

Question: are there any common practices or suggestions for this case?

I'm thinking of adding a dummy variable to the template constructor, however, I'm not happy with this.

**UPD** A little explanation of what I'm doing:

I'm doing an acyclic-graph-like structure. Users of my library are expected to write their graphs in the following manner:

```
auto x = graph::NodeType1();
auto y = graph::NodeType2();
auto z = graph::NodeType3(x, y);
// ... etc.
```

All node classes are derived from the base class (called `C` in this question). In the constructor of the base class I need to know actual types of parent nodes, that's why I'm doing a template constructor.

I'm fine with disallowing copy construction of nodes. In fact, there's no sane definition of the copy operation for a node. However, simply declaring copy constructor as deleted does not do the thing I want.

Comment: *"case when I want copy construction is indistinguishable from the case when I want to call template constructor with a single argument of type `C`."* No it isn't. The copy constructor wins in overload resolution. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: My problem is that sometimes I want to call template constructor with a single argument of type `C`.

Comment: There might be some way to do this, but it does not look like good design.

Comment: Yes, that's why I've asked this question. I also think about making my constructor to accept `std::tuple<T...>`. Than copy construction is C c2{c} and calling template constructor is `C c2{std::make_tuple(c)}`. A little bit batter than adding a dummy variable (assuming that copy construction is cheap)

Comment: The more interesting question is: Why does the state of the new object depend on which constructor is called if the source object is the same? That doesn't seem logical.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I've updated the question. In short: copy constructor creates a copy of a node of a graph, and calling template constructor create a new node with an edge to the nodes passed to constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tag Dispatching** is a used idiom to give a function a distinct signature, similar to your "dummy variable" idea.

```
struct UseSpecialConstructor{};

template <typename ...T>
explicit C(UseSpecialConstructor, const T&...) { /* implementation */ };
```

When inlined, compilers are good at optimizing away this unused empty struct parameter, and calling code gains readability from your explicit tag name.

```
C c1;
C c2{ C::UseSpecialConsructor{}, c1 };
```

Comment: Yeah, this is how I'm going to solve this. I'm also going to provide a function `make_c` which would save users from passing the UseSpecialConsructor thing around.